# How to validate an incoming webhook GET request from the Twilio API using Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, twilio, sms, twilio-api

I have figured out how to validate incoming POST webhook requests from the Twilio API in Node.  Now I am trying to do the same with a GET request.  It keeps failing the validation.  I have found very few good examples online of how to do a GET request.

Here is the relevant section of my NodeJS Express route:

```js
router.get('/postatus', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('route /postatus');
    // we first need to make sure that the request actually came from Twilio,
    // so this code is to validate that incoming request
    const authToken = process.env.MY_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN_VAR;
    let url = 'https://myurl.com';
    
    let params = req.query;
    console.log({params});
    url += "?" + Object.keys(params).map(key => key + '=' + params[key]).join('&');
    params = {};
    
    const twilioSignature = req.headers['x-twilio-signature'];
    
    const validRequest = client.validateRequest(authToken, twilioSignature, url, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work the same way as for POST. Maybe your not parsing the parameters the right way. I'd recommend using the [`twilio.webhook()`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-express-app-by-validating-incoming-twilio-requests#use-twilio-express-request-validation-middleware) middleware as it avoids bugs and also makes the code easier to read.

```js
// Middleware to handle secured route for HTTP GET and HTTP POST
app.use("/secured", twilio.webhook({
  authToken: process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
}), (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("This is a secured route");
  res.header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  res.send("<Response><Message>This route is secured</Message></Response>")
});
```